# What does a linear function look like in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am told that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear function of $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$. If $N=1$ I know that I can write for some $m,q\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x) = mx + q
$$
If $N>1$ what is a general form I can write this in? Maybe this?
$$
f(x) = m^\top x
$$

Comment: This is not the mathematical use of “linear” past high school.

Answer (score -1):

In general, a "linear function" in $\mathbb{R}^N$ looks like $$f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{m}^\intercal \mathbf{x} + b$$

Comment: Shouldn't $b$ be a scalar? And is it always the case that a linear function $\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ looks like the one above?

Comment: @Physics_Student you are right, I have edited my answer

Comment: For me, what you wrote is an *affine* function. Only the first term is linear.

Comment: @Bernard look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function, you claim doesn't make sense then even in the 1D case. But actually, functions of the form $f(x) = a\,x+b$ are called linear in 1D!

Comment: These do not satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ nor $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$! In the context of vector spaces, *linear* does not mean  ‘a polynomial of degree $1$’.

Comment: @Bernard you are taking about linear functionals or linear operators! Not linear functions in a Euclidean space!

Comment: In Bourbaki, this is called an affine function.